# Swift- NSTimer crashing app

Tags: ios, swift, timer, nstimer

In Xcode I have this:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Foundation

var position = 0
var gameTimer = NSTimer()

class ViewController: UIViewController {


        @IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {

            gameTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: "runTimedCode:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

            func runTimedCode() {

                position = Int(arc4random_uniform(11))


            }}}
```

When I run this app it crashes and returns the error: `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT.`

I have run the script without the NSTimer and it works perfectly.
I have also run it with and without the colon and it returns the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

- Put `func runTimedCode()` out of the scope of `@IBAction button()`. Selector / target methods must be on the top level of the class.
- Either remove the colon of `runTimedCode:` or declare `runTimedCode` as `runTimedCode(timer: NSTimer)`. Each colon in a `Selector` represents one parameter.

Comment: How would I be able to run the activate the timer and function when the button is pressed?

Comment: Leave the line to initialize and start the timer in the `IBAction` method. Or consider to write `startTimer()` and `stopTimer()` methods to maintain the timer reliably.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues:

1. You have defined your `runTimedCode` function inside your `button` function rather than as an instance function
2. You have specified the correct selector signature `runTimedCode:` (with the colon) but you have not specified the `NSTimer` argument that will be sent to this function (which is what is indicated by the : in the selector).  You want:

---

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
 import Foundation

var position = 0
var gameTimer : NSTimer?  // Don't assign a value just to keep the compiler happy - if the variable is an optional declare it as such

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.gameTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: "runTimedCode:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

    func runTimedCode(timer:NSTimer) {
            position = Int(arc4random_uniform(11))
    }
}
```